# Выборка одинаковых наименований в массиве, суммирование их количества и склеивание строк

Tags: python

Новичок в Python, понимаю что задача достаточно легкая, но мне кажется я решаю её слишком сложно и с большим количеством костылей.

Задача следующая, есть данные вида:

```py
test_l = [
          ('res10', 1, '2'),
          ('res2', 3, '4'),
          ('res4', 12, '1'),
          ('res10', 2, '1'),
          ('res2', 3, '4'),
          ('res5', 1, '5')
         ]
```

Нужно:

1. Выбрать одинаковые элементы по названию (1 колонка)
2. У одинаковых элементов просуммировать количество (2 колонка)
3. У одинаковых элементов склеить номер заявки из 3 колонки к виду '1, 2, 3'

Я делаю это следующим образом:

```py
test_l.sort()  # сортирую по названию

test_2 = []  # массив для готовых данных

for ind_unit, unit in enumerate(test_l):
    incr: int = 1
    count: int = unit[1]
    request: str = unit[2]

    # проверка на последний элемент, чтобы выйти из цикла, 
    # если он не повторяется
    if ind_unit + 1 == len(test_l):
        test_2.append((unit[0], count, request))
        break

    # цикл, проходящий по всем повторяющимся элементам
    while unit[0] == test_l[ind_unit + incr][0]:
        count += test_l[ind_unit + incr][1]
        request += ', ' + test_l[ind_unit + incr][2]
        incr += 1

    # добавление в итоговый массив просуммированного элемента
    if ind_unit == 0 or unit[0] != test_l[ind_unit - incr][0]:
        test_2.append((unit[0], count, request))
```

Наверняка можно сделать более понятно и просто, без лишних проверок. Буду рад подсказкам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby


data = [
          ('res10', 1, '2'),
          ('res2', 3, '4'),
          ('res4', 12, '1'),
          ('res10', 2, '1'),
          ('res2', 3, '4'),
          ('res5', 1, '5')
         ]


data = sorted(data)

res = []

for (key, group) in groupby(data, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    value = 0
    nums = []
    for elem in group:
        value += elem[1]
        nums.append(elem[2])
    item = (key, value, ', '.join(sorted(nums)))
    res.append(item)

print(res)
```

Comment: NB: Для такого простого примера мой код вполне хорош, но если много и часто приходится работать с табличными данными, и нужно по всякому их агрегировать и обрабатывать, то лучше заморочиться и освоить pandas.

Answer (score 3):

Решение с использованием модуля [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
In [55]: import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

In [56]: df = pd.DataFrame(test_l, columns=["id", "val1", "val2"])
```

получился следующий DataFrame:

```
In [57]: df
Out[57]:
      id  val1 val2
0  res10     1    2
1   res2     3    4
2   res4    12    1
3  res10     2    1
4   res2     3    4
5   res5     1    5
```

решение:

```
In [58]: res = df.sort_values("val2").groupby("id").agg({"val1": "sum", "val2": ', '.join})
```

результат:

```
In [59]: res
Out[59]:
       val1  val2
id
res10     3  1, 2
res2      6  4, 4
res4     12     1
res5      1     5
```

результат в виде "Vanilla Python" списка:

```
In [60]: res.reset_index().to_numpy().tolist()
Out[60]:
[['res10', 3, '1, 2'],
 ['res2', 6, '4, 4'],
 ['res4', 12, '1'],
 ['res5', 1, '5']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ по заданию:

```py
test_l = [
  ('res10', 1, '2'),
  ('res2', 3, '4'),
  ('res4', 12, '1'),
  ('res10', 2, '1'),
  ('res2', 3, '4'),
  ('res5', 1, '5')
]

ind = 0

res_list = dict()

out_test_l = [

]

repeated_res_name_list = set()

# test_l[0] = ('res', 0, '2')

print(test_l)

for col1, col2, col3 in test_l:
  # print(res_list)
  if col1 not in res_list:
    res_list[col1]= ind
    out_test_l.append((col1,col2,col3))
    ind += 1
  else:
    pred_index = res_list[col1]
    _, p_col2, p_col3 = out_test_l[pred_index]
    out_test_l[pred_index] = (col1, p_col2+col2, p_col3+','+col3)
    repeated_res_name_list.add(col1)

# print(out_test_l)
# print(repeated_res_name_list)

ans = [i for i in out_test_l if i[0] in repeated_res_name_list]
print(ans)
```

Ссылка на [Online Compiler](https://repl.it/repls/CulturedDefiantApplicationprogram)

Comment: Это не выглядит "более понятным и простым")

Comment: Зато использует одно прохождение, а не цикл в цикле )